bottom navigation : The way to reduce the space below the text
There is too much space below the icon and text, as shown in the following picture.

Could you let me know how I can reduce this?
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:itemPaddingTop="10dp"
        app:itemIconSize="27dp"
        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BtmNavSelectedTextStyle"
        app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BtmNavUnselectedTextStyle"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
        app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_nav" />

I tried reducing the height, but the position of the icon and text didn't change, and only the height got shorter, causing the top of the icon to be cut off.

If I understand your question correctly, try using app:itemPaddingBottom to set padding from your text to the bottom of BottomNavigationView. For example: app:itemPaddingBottom="0dp" will make your text stick to the bottom line of BottomNavigationView

@NguyenTienDung
I tried it, but the space between the icon and the text increases instead of the space below the text.

set height to wrap_content
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    app:itemPaddingTop="10dp"
    app:itemIconSize="27dp"
    app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BtmNavSelectedTextStyle"
    app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BtmNavUnselectedTextStyle"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
    app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"
    app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@android:color/transparent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_nav" />


I've tried this too, but the same thing happens

If you are using this in an Activity then,
remove these following lines form the onCreate() method,
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
insets
}
And Add this following lines
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
val params = binding.bottomNavigationView.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
params.bottomMargin = insets.systemWindowInsetBottom
binding.bottomNavigationView.layoutParams = params
insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets()
}
And If you are using it in a fragment then,
remove these following lines form the onCreate() method of the host activity,
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
insets
}
And Add this following lines to the onViewCreated() method of the fragment
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(view) { v, insets ->
val params = binding.bottomNavigationView.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
params.bottomMargin = insets.systemWindowInsetBottom
binding.bottomNavigationView.layoutParams = params
insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets()
}
this will solve the extra space issue.
